# How to a access certain value with the help of an attribute

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I am trying to implement multi-language support into my program. In order to do, so I want to use XML. The file has different items, and all of them get one element of the according language and the text in that language.

And then I want to read the XML file and create a dictionary, so that I can set the text of the elements according to the items with the corresponding language.

But I am totally inexperienced with XML, and so I don't know how to do that.

I understood I need to use a Deserializer, and found some code of how to use it. But I cannot figure out, how to distinguish between different items and get only one child of them.

I know my English isn't the best, so here some more explanations, to make it a bit more clear.

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Explanations>
    <Element name="Start">
        <English>Start here.</English>
        <German>Starte hier.</German>
    </Element>
    <Element name="End">
        <English>It ends here.</English>
        <German>Es endet hier.</German>
    </Element>
</Explanations>
```

So what I want now: When the user is in the start state, and has selected English as his language, I want the text to be "Start here." but when he had selected German I want it to be "Starte hier.".

I don't really understand how my C# class has to look, since most of the examples I found were not with more than one child in the total XML file.

And I also don't understand how I access the according text. Is there a way to use something like `text = XML_text.Start.German`? I really don't understand the usage of XML in C#. Sorry.

And actually, I want to store everything in a dictionary. So my dictionary will be a bit strange, since I need 3 fields.

```
Dictonary<string, Dictonary<string,string>>
```

The 1st string stands for the state of the program. The 2nd string is for the selected language, and the 3rd string is finally for the text itself.

So I can access the text in way like:

```
text = Dictonary["Start"].Dictonary["German"]
```

But I am sure that's not the correct syntax, But I can figure that out somehow.

I really hope you can help me with that.

Comment: `text = Dictonary["Start"]["German"]`

Comment: Why are you trying to use XML for this? What is your technology stack (WPF, Xamarin, MAUI, WinForms, ...)? If you use any of the common UI frameworks, you could use localization using resource files (.resx).

Comment: @Poul Thanks for the quick and easy solution for the adressing a value in a double dictonary system.

Comment: @ewerspej It is just a simple programm, with not more than 100 lines of text in total. The person who will edit the texts in the future won't be a programmer. So I thought a human readable file is the easiest to edit for such a person. - Oh an I am using Unity for the program, since it is some kind of simulator, and that part is pretty easy with Unity.

Comment: Resource (.resx) files are also XML-based and Visual Studio comes with a human friendly editor for them and there are also useful extensions like this one to manage translations easily: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.ResXManager

Comment: I don't see why resx files shall be better than plain XML. Also we are not using Visual Studio. Is the way I want it to do such a terrible way? The texts are only for explaining how to use the simulator. There won't be much more added and changes will be rare. I just need the correct C# class and a way to access to fields. I hope it is not that hard to make that work.

Comment: No, it's not a terrible way at all, I just prefer resx as it comes exactly for that kind of purpose. Which IDE are you using and on which platform are you? Rider works just as well.